# Calling JSON Link and filtering using Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, json, wordpress

I have this code where i am displaying data from a database using a json link which calls the read.php file and displays it on my wordpress site. At the moment i am stuck since i need to filter the table according to which column the user selects from the Dropdown List.

Note: I am also using the JSON Content Importer Plugin to call the link

**HTML Code and Script**

```
<label for="league">Choose a League:</label>
<select id="league">
  <option value="premierleague">Premier League</option>
  <option value="seriea">Serie A</option>
  <option value="bundesliga">Bundesliga</option>
  <option value="laliga">La Liga</option>
  <option value="ligue1">Ligue 1</option>
</select>
<br><br><br><br>
<table>
  <thead>
<tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Shoes</th>
   <th id=league>Premier League</th>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
[jsoncontentimporter url=https://soccerdirect.net/statistics/read.php?id=1 basenode=data]
 <tr>
     <td>{id}</td>
     <td>{shoes}</td>
     <td>{premierleague}</td>
 </tr>
[/jsoncontentimporter]
</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#league').change(function() {
    var selection = $(this).val();
     var dataset = $('table').find('tr');
    dataset.show();
    dataset.filter(function(index, item) {
      return $(item).find('td:first-child').text().split(',').indexOf(selection) === -1;
    }).hide();
  });
});
</script>
</html>
```

**Table**

[Database Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AylMZ.png)

**HTML Table**

[HTML Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vWhq.png)

Comment: Can you show an example of the HTML table structure with JSON data filled in? Just a couple of rows suffice.

Comment: Yes i added the HTML

Comment: I want to filter the JSON using the Dropdown i made as shown in the last image

Comment: I meant show the HTML of the table structure with JSON data filled in; i.e. the generated code :-)

Comment: The other rows then fill in automatically as you can see in the image

Comment: Several things look wrong: 1) your third <th> has the same id as your select. 2) you are filtering the first <td> in each <tr> ('td:first-child') which is the ID; however you want to filter by league.

Comment: Yes exactly, how can i do this pls cause i couldnt find any similar examples

Comment: First you have to figure out what to filter. In the JSON file (https://soccerdirect.net/statistics/read.php?id=1) each node has premierleague, seriea, bundesliga etc. So if every node contains all of the options in the select, your filter result would show all nodes. Now, what exactly do you want to filter?

Comment: I just need to show the ID, Shoes and Premier League columns when premier league is selected for example

Comment: Those are already shown as per your code. Please provide clarification by showing what the rendered HTML looks like.

Comment: It is shown in the last image

Comment: The rendered code, please.